# Laravel & Livewire: How to execute a javascript function when the component changes?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm using Laravel 8 and Livewire. I have an application that shows `items` objects from a table. When you click on an `item`, it displays the `item` details to the right.

```
<ul>
@foreach ($items as $item)
  <li wire:click="show({{ $item->id }})" class="...">
      {{ $item->name }}
  </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

This works great, since the `show()` method in the component will do anything it does, binding variables, and such...

Now, in the details section, I want to make a chart, a line chart. I have done it using d3js, and it works fine the first time I render the page, since my `item` variable has already a default value (last item in the table)

When I click on other `item` it shows the data, but the chart doesn't change its data, it is stuck with the data it got the first time it loaded.

I followed some solutions that said I have to send a `contentChanged` event to the browser, but it doesn't seem to work.

In my component, after changing the selection I have:

```
$this->dispatchBrowserEvent('contentChanged');
```

To simplify things, in my blade, I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener('contentChanged', e => {
    alert('{{ $item->name }}')
  })
</script>
```

Yes, it executes the function and show an alert, but the `$item` has the data from the first time the page was loaded. It doesn't take the new `$item` that changed on click.

What should I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass in data to the browser-event that is emitted,

```php
$this->dispatchBrowserEvent('contentChanged', ['item' => $item]);
```

Then you can retrieve that information in the events `data` attribute,

```js
window.addEventListener('contentChanged', (e) => {
    alert(e.detail.item.name);
});
```